# Filling compound field programatically fails with EntityMetadataWrapperException

Tags: 7, entities

I followed the instruction in the post from [here](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/compound-fields-in-drupal-7/) to create a compound field and it work like a charm. Now I am trying to fill each of the 3 "columns" that make the compound field programmatically and I can figure it out how.

I am using the entity API to create the node see the code below:

```
$node = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'MY-CONTENT-TYPE'));
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',  $node);

$data = array('column_1'=>'value 1', 'column_2'=>'value 2', 'column_3'=>'value 3');

$entity->field_custom_compound_field = $data;

$entity->save();
```

But it does not work. What am I missing?

Note: I keep getting the error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_custom_compound_field.

Comment: By 'compound' do you mean a standard field that's got more than one value column? I've not come across the notion of 'sub-fields' before in Drupal, would be good to clear up what that refers to. Off the top of my head try changing the 4th code line to `$entity->field_custom_compound_field[] = $data;` and see what differences that makes

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. I call them sub fields because the make the compound field.

Comment: Cool, Drupal refers to them as 'columns' in case you need to know that at any point. The bottom line is every field can potentially have more than one column (even those that don't) so setting them through a metadata wrapper will be exactly the same; the array will just have extra key/value pairs in it

Comment: Hi Clive thank you for the correction, I didn't know they were called columns I have updated the question with the right terminology and I also added the error I am getting.

Comment: Looks like Entity API doesn't know about the field - if you `dpm($entity->value()` (assume Devel module is installed) do you see any data under `field_custom_compound_field`?

Comment: I can manually add data to the columns of the field going to node/add/content-type and I can see the data saved into the columns in the database and using dpm() or the Devel tab in the node page. With your suggestion I get this error: EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format.

Comment: What about `$data = array(array('column_1'=>'value 1', 'column_2'=>'value 2', 'column_3'=>'value 3'));` with your original method? (not at a dev environment at the moment so I'm just guessing)

Comment: I actually have it like that because the compound field have have unlimited values. So to answer, no, it does not work like that either. I even try they data array without the column names and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this here in case someone is having the same issue:

I use the tutorial located [here](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/compound-fields-in-drupal-7/) to create my compound custom field with multiple columns what I didn't noticed was in the hook_fields_field_info() implementation I should define the type of data the entity will take. To make things worse in the tutorial the author use the example where all the fields he created are text fields, but in my case I have date, decimal and text fields so I had to define each type. I found the solution in this [post](http://www.thecarneyeffect.co.uk/describe-field-properties-make-custom-fields-work-entity-metadata-wrappers).

In a nutshell in my hook_fields_field_info() implementation I have to declare the entity property type, but since I am using multiple columns on the field I have to implement a call back function that will allow me to define the property type for each of my columns.

```
/**
* Implements hook_field_info().
*
* Provides the description of the field.
*/
function field_example_field_info() {
  return array(
  // We name our field as the associative name of the array.
    'field_example_rgb' => array(
      'label' => t('Example Color RGB'),
      'description' => t('Demonstrates a field composed of an RGB color.'),
      'default_widget' => 'field_example_3text',
      'default_formatter' => 'field_example_simple_text',
      'property_type' => 'field_example_rgb', // we add the propert type here
      'property_callbacks' => array('field_example_rgb_property_info_callback'), // we add the callback
    ),
  );
}
```

Call back function to define each columns type:

```
function field_example_rgb_property_info_callback(&$info, $entity_type, $field, $instance, $field_type) {
  $property = &$info[$entity_type]['bundles'][$instance['bundle']]['properties'][$field['field_name']];

  $property['getter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_get';
  $property['setter callback'] = 'entity_metadata_field_verbatim_set';
  unset($property['query callback']);

  $property['property info']['rgb'] = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => t('RGB'),
    'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',
  );
  $property['property info']['someothervalue'] = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => t('Some other value'),
    'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set',
  );
}
```

After doing that the following code:

```
$node = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'MY-CONTENT-TYPE'));
$entity = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',  $node);

$data = array('column_1'=>'value 1', 'column_2'=>'value 2', 'column_3'=>'value 3');

$entity->field_custom_compound_field = $data;

$entity->save();
```

Worked like a charm.